# Selenium - horizontal scrolling using button click

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-ide

I am new to selenium and was trying few stuffs which could actually make my tasks easier.

Here is a url - https://www.starz.com/movies

I am trying to click the arrow button at the right corner of the page under popular category but i couldn't. Also, i would have to click it n number of times until all movies are loaded under that category.

Here is the bit of code that i tried.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class selenium {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {

        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.starz.com/movies");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Selenium\\geckodriver.exe");

        driver.findElement(By.id("popular")).click();
    }
}
```

The above code works but it does not click the arrow button, instead it clicks the movie that is placed at the center under popular category.

Answer (score 0):

You need to click `<button>` element instead of `<div>`:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class selenium {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {

        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.starz.com/movies");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Selenium\\geckodriver.exe");

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='popular']//button[@class='slider-next slick-arrow']")).click();
    }
}
```

Comment: The code mentioned by you is not working. The xpath used by you does not have a category name specified.

Comment: Ok. `XPath` bound to exact category

Answer (score 0):

`By.id("popular")` will give you the entire row. All the arrows have the same class, `sz-icon-arrow-next`, so you need to use the popular row and the arrow locator to locate the arrow

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#popular .sz-icon-arrow-next")).click();
```

**EDIT**

If you want to click the arrow to the end locate it into list and check if its still exist

```
int size = 1;
while (size > 0) {
    List<WebElement> arrow = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("#popular .sz-icon-arrow-next"));
    size = arrow.size();
    if (size > 0) {
        arrow.get(0).click();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This seems to be working for me but clicks only once. Is there a way to make it click until all movies in the list are over ? 

i used a simple for-statement for testing purpose but getting [org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not visible] exception after the arrow button disappears. 

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
   driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#popular .sz-icon-arrow-next")).click();
   Thread.sleep(5000);
  }

Comment: Works like a charm(sometime it fails due to loading issue, i am using thread.sleep in such cases).

Comment: Is there any function to first focus on an element before executing an action. Say, i perform an action it works only if i manually crawl the page until the element is visible.

Comment: @love_to_learn Have a look at [Actions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html#moveToElement-org.openqa.selenium.WebElement-) class